# Is there way to use a popup with Flask-Login instead of creating a login form?

Tags: python, flask, basic-authentication, flask-login

I'm creating a Flask app for non-devs who won't know how to pass headers into Postman. So I'm wondering if there's a way to trigger a dialog popup in the event the user hasn't passed in a header when accessing my flask application?

I've tried the following, and I'm seeing that this doesn't work. I'm coming to the conclusion that if I use flask-login then I'm going to need to create an html page?

```py
@login_manager.request_loader
def load_user(request):
    try: 
        username = request.replace('Basic ', '', 1)
        user_data = auth.authenticate_user_by_username(username)
        user = User(user_data)
        return user
    except:
        make_response('Could not verify!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})
        username = request.authorization.username
        user_data_from_browser = auth.authenticate_user_by_username(username)
        if user_data_from_browser is None:
            return None
        else:
            return user_data_from_browser
```

I have also tried returning the `make_response(..)` and as you know Flask login will get mad because it won't possess its properties from the UserMixin class.

Comment: Hey! Just for clarification: Will these non-dev users interact with your app using Postman or a regular browser?

Comment: Only the browser